# Transpose or unpivot columns of software into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I have a SQL 2008 table containing one row for each computer with many columns of software titles:

```
Computer      Col1        Col2        Col3          Col4
PC1           Acrobat     Word        Excel
PC2           Word        Access      
PC3           Google
PC4           Word        Excel       SQL2008       Maximizer
```

I would like to combine it in to two columns like this:

```
Computer        Software
PC1             Acrobat
PC1             Word
PC1             Excel
PC2             Word
PC2             Access
PC3             Google
PC4             Word
PC4             Excel
PC4             SQL2008
PC4             Maximizer
```

It's not an aggregate of the columns, so does unpivot or transpose work?

Each row has from 1 to 32 columns of data.
There are hundreds of different values for the software names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot the data a few different ways including the UNPIVOT function or a CROSS APPLY to convert the multiple columns into rows.

**[UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):**

```
select computer, software
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  software 
  for col in ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4])
) un;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee779/1).

**CROSS APPLY:**

```
select t.computer, c.software
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  select col1 union all
  select col2 union all
  select col3 union all
  select col4
) c (software)
where c.software is not null;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee779/2). You could also use CROSS APPLY with VALUES depending on your version of SQL Server:

```
select t.computer, c.software
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  values
    (col1), (col2),
    (col3), (col4)
) c (software)
where c.software is not null;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee779/3)